# Why do I get an error like this in promela?

Tags: verification, model-checking, promela, spin

I am a beginner with promela and SPIN. I have a small code in promela but I do not understand why I have the error mentioned below:

```
chan config =[16] of {short};
bool get_type = false;
short car_type = 4;

active proctype control() {
start:
    do
        :: get_type == false ->
            config!car_type;
            printf("type sent");
        :: printf("type not received");
    od
}

active proctype robot() {
sleep:
    config?car_type ->
        get_type = true ;
        printf("type received= %d", car_type);
}
```

Error:

```
    using statement merging
      1: proc 0, no matching stmnt 91
    #processes: 2
      1:    proc  1 (robot:1) mytest.pml:16 (state 1)
      1:    proc  0 (control:1) mytest.pml:7 (state 5)
    2 processes created
    Exit-Status 0
```

Comment: @PatrickTrentin , thank you , i made the code

Comment: @PatrickTrentin , thank you for your advise, i changed my code to minimal and reproducible one , home i will get some help , thank you

Comment: @PatrickTrentin all variables are declared, i didn't made it here .i will update the code to can see them

Comment: @PatrickTrentin i updated the code. thank you for your help

Comment: @PatrickTrentin, i think i resolved the error was on file , i changed the file .pml and i past the same code , and now it work !! i do not know why ! do you have an idea ?